# How to fill the second dropdown with the same value as the first dropdown

Tags: c#, dropdown

I have 2 databounded dropdownlist. They have the same value(all months).

I want that, if a user choose (in the first Dropdown) for example april then the second Dropdown should jump automatically to April.

The only thing I could think of was:

```html
protected void ddMonthfrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddMonthfrom.SelectedItem.Text = ddMonthto.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

It does not work. When I click on April the second Dropdown does not Change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ddMonthto.SelectedValue = ddMonthfrom.SelectedItem.Value;`

- OnFristDropDownSelectedIndexChange (ddMonthfrom)
- Set the value of the Second DropDown (ddMonthto).

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same values in both Drop Downs then remove the text portion

```
ddMonthfrom.SelectedItem = ddMonthto.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ddMonthfrom.SelectedIndex = ddMonthfrom.FindStringExact(ddMonthto.Text);
```

This should also work if the comboBox `ddMonthto` doesn't have a `DataSource`.

**Notes:**

- You can also use `.SelectedItem.ToString()` instead of `.Text`, while `.SelectedItem.Text` isn't correct.
- If you populate your comboBox using a datasource, you can just use the same datasource for both comboBoxes, and the same item should be selected automatically.

Hope that helps :)